# AdMob SDK Upgrade without code?

Tags: android, admob, apk

I have 2 fairly successful games on Google Play.  They have remained unchanged since 2012 since all bugs were ironed out.

The apps both use AdMob.

A couple of weeks back, ads stopped being served due to AdMob SDK Update, and our very old SDK is no longer supported / served by AdMob.

Unfortunately, my ex-business partner who created the app code, lost the code and we subsequently fell out years ago.

So I have 2 APK's, with no real idea how they were built, with old AdMob SDK.

Is there a way for me to upgrade the AdMob SDK in these APK's?

Comment: Build the game again and publish it via your old game keystore and same package name.

Comment: How do I build it without code?

Comment: Make a new code. The important part is that you have keystore and packagename of the app. Since the game is already popular you will just make another code from scratch, and profit on the long run.

Comment: Don't have the keystore.

Comment: Then you lost your game forever. Even if you had the whole code you couldn't update it.

Answer (score 0):

The is no way to do this.
SDKs are used by the compiler to build the app. You need to build it again with this newer SDK.
There is no way to rebuild the app if you don't have the code. 
Try to get the code back. There is no other way, sorry.